# Pejorative name for a person who brazenly tells a lie

Tags: word-request, slang

I'll set a scene here: James owes me $20. When I asked him about it, he said that he had already paid back. So James is a ____? Google told me that *thick-skinned* and *callous* could be used here but I'm not sure if it sounds natural.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still a little unsure what you are trying to convey; I don't see what the criticisms are in your example, could you give an additional one? Is the situation that, despite the evidence, he is unwilling to change his belief that he payed you? As in he's stubborn? Also what kind of tone are you looking for? A common word, slang/idioms, or a big word (only people with large vocabularies would know it)?

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I want a slang for someone who would tell the most blatant lies over their own petty interest. It's kind of like "brazen" and "shameless" but more informal and preferably in noun form. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That person is a  **[bald-faced liar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bald-faced)**.

Comment: A very minor correction: that should be **a** bald-faced liar.

Comment: I think I would say bare faced liar, but the meaning is clearly the same. A regional variation perhaps? (I am in the UK)

Comment: **baldfaced** is probably used more frequently in the US than in England, though I think it might go back to Middle English **balled**. See #4  "glib or crafty".  here http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=11106576&egdisplay=open&egs=11115229